# "If needed" Vs. "If it's needed"

Tags: passive-voice, idiomatic-language

What's more idiomatic in the following contexts? If needed, or "If **it's** needed".

Here are some examples that I came across:

> 1. I have an insurance for my country only. But I can buy another
>      insurance for abroad. **If needed** / **if it's needed**.
> 2. You can go there tomorrow by yourself. But I can come to help, **if
>      needed / if it's needed**.
> 3. They can send you more products, **if needed / if they're needed**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say, in my experience as a native British English speaker, that "if needed" would be the most usual, and "if necessary" slightly stronger or more formal. "If it's needed" would actually be quite unusual, less common than "if it's necessary".

See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if%20needed%2Cif%20it%20is%20needed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20needed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20it%20is%20needed%3B%2Cc0): 
[image]